# Ruby - Radio button form for custom attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Let's say I have a class like this one:

```
class Something
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

And the class category is something like this:

```
class Category
   field :name
end
```

I am making a form where using radio buttons you can select what categories that something belongs to, my problem is how can I achieve that?

What I have tried is the following:

```
<table>
  <% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.label :category, #{cat.name} %>
        <%= f.radio_button, #{cat} %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I have tried other variations with "#{cat}" or "#{cat.name}" or just cat. These without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your form (`f.radio_button` on the question) for `Something` model, you need to reference `category_id` on the form, try this:

```
<table>
  <% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.radio_button :category_id, "#{cat.id}", :id => "radio-#{cat.id}" %>
        <label for="radio-#{cat.id}"><%= cat.name %></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```